# Don't show blocks on some pages

Tags: 7, blocks

I don't want to show blocks inside some pages, and I can't touch the theme files.

Is there any way to do this programmatically inside a module?

Comment: it can also be done through the configuration of the individual blocks you want to limit... without any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_block_list_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7) to hide the blocks in your module code. See docs for more information on how to achieve this. This is the the alter for the function Drupal used to hide/show blocks.

Comment: thanks man,, sorry for late but finaly your answer is correct and works for me

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not hide all blocks because `system_block` contains your page markup.
2. You can use [hook_page_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) to hide unwanted blocks.